# Build single class in IntelliJ using dependencies previously built by maven

Tags: java, maven, build, intellij-idea

I have a application using a maven build and am using IntelliJ IDEA. Both Maven and IntelliJ build classes into the same target folder, however whenever I choose to rebuild a single class in IntelliJ it complains that it cannot find it's dependencies, even if maven just built them and they are in the output folders. If I do a full rebuild in IntelliJ it will build the class.

How do I make IntelliJ use the classes maven built as dependencies for the single class it is building?

Comment: Please share a project to reproduce, there are many cases with complex dependencies configuration when it may not work as you expect.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Are you saying this would normally work? Meaning something about either my maven or IntelliJ setup is causing this not to work as intended.

Comment: I've talked to the responsible developer, explicit compilation should work according to him if dependent classes are available in the classpath. IDEA adds output directory to classpath automatically, so no extra configuration is required if Maven and IDEA are building to the same location.

Answer (score 0):

If it's purely class files, I'm not sure why it'd be complaining if they're all under the directory you have configured IntelliJ to use for the project's compiled classes.

More frequently, what I've run into is the build creates some things other than class files and you have to create a library that points at that other stuff so that IntelliJ knows about them. Another wrinkle are resource files as those are hunted for relative to the project's working directory which is, by default, usually the root directory of the project which is rarely correct as most resources are dumped under a "build" or "deploy" directory.

If all else fails, you should be able to spit out verbose Maven build info and compare the classpath it's using at compile time to the one that IntelliJ uses to try and figure out where they differ.